# VBA How to use a variable between subs?

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I'm pretty new to VBA and I don't know how to use a variable between subs. The code should be pretty self explanatory:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim strWeapon As String
If Target.Address = "$I$8" Then
    MsgBox "You pick up a sword"
    strWeapon = "Sword"
ElseIf Target.Address = "$I$9" Then
    MsgBox "You pick up a magic staff"
    strWeapon = "Magic"
ElseIf Target.Address = "$I$10" Then
    MsgBox "You pick up a bow and arrows"
    strWeapon = "Bow"
End If
End Sub

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If strWeapon = "Magic" Then
    UserForm1.Show
ElseIf strWeapon = "Sword" Then
    UserForm2.Show
ElseIf strWeapon = "Bow" Then
    UseForm2.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Is there a way I can use strWeapon in both subs? I get an error for not defining the variable strWeapon in the second sub.
Thank you!

Comment: do you mean as a `String` variable that is updated and can be dispalyed in both `Sub`s ? you can use the `Public strWeapon as String` , put this code line (for conviniance) above both `Subs` , under the `Option Explicit`

Comment: declare strWeapon outside the sub Worksheet_SelectionChange globally

Comment: I added it like you guys said to do and removed Dim strweapon as string at the top and now nothing happens when I click the commandButton

Comment: where is your `CommandButton1` ? on which User_Form ? what exactly is your code suppose to do?

Comment: On second thoughts, your question is actually, "How do I keep a variable assigned after the sub routine has finished", is it not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. You can use a public variable as shai rado has mentioned- this is probably easiest, however you should limit the use of public variables where possible.
2. You can pass the variable from one sub to another like this:

   ```
   sub Main()
       dim strWeapon as string
       strWeapon = "Fork"
       WillIWin strWeapon
   end sub

   sub WillIWin(strWeapon as string)
       select case strWeapon
           case "Gun"
               msgbox "Probably"
           case "Sword"
               msgbox "unlikely"
           case "Fork"
               Msgbox "Goodluck"
       end select
   End Sub
   ```
3. Alternatively if you have multiple variables to pass, you might be better with a class, this option takes more work than I'm willing to put in here, but CPearson has a good introductory course for them.

Answer (score 1):

yes!

`Public strWeapon as String`

At the top of any module, do the following:

tpye `Option Explicit` then immediately below, put the Public declaration.
this can then be used in any other subroutine OR module within your excel project