# VBA Excel Dim and Set 2 workbook files with FilePicker and work with them

Tags: excel, vba, set, filepicker

I would like to pick, open, set and work ( copy data from 1 file to another) with 2 Workbooks.

For this I have a 3rd .xlsm file where I have the following code to pick, open and set the 1st Workbook with "wbfinal".

```
Sub SelectFinalFileOptima()

'select final file

Dim directory As String
Dim FileNameFinal As String
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Dim wbfinal As Workbook

  Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select the Optima Final file from last month."
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Optima Final", "*.xlsx"

    If .Show = True Then
      FileNameFinal = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))

    End If
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Workbooks.Open (FileNameFinal)
  'Workbooks(FileNameFinal).Close
  
  Set wbfinal = Workbooks(FileNameFinal)

End Sub
```

After both files are opened I would like to Activate the 1st file to start working on with the following code:

```
Sub WorkWithFinalFile()

Workbooks(wbfinal).Activate


End Sub
```

However this doesn't work for me.
Can someone see what I'm missing?

Update, I also add the code of the other file o be picked here below:

```
Sub SelectWorkingFileOptima()

' select working file

Dim directory As String
Dim FileNameWorking As String
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Dim wbworking As Workbook

  Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select the Optima Working file from last month."
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Optima Working", "*.xlsx"

    If .Show = True Then
      FileNameWorking = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))

    End If
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Workbooks.Open (FileNameWorking)
  ' when needed
  'Workbooks(FileNameWorking).Close
  
  Set wbworking = Workbooks(FileNameWorking)

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to pass the variable from one sub to the other for this to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904181/vba-how-to-use-a-variable-between-subs

Comment: Just note that you'll have to use `WorkWithFinalFile wbfinal.Name` and `Sub WorkWithFinalFile(wbfinal As String)` if you're using `Workbooks(wbfinal)`

Comment: 1. If you use **the same Sub to pick both files**, `wbfinal` will be **the last picked one**. Even so, the scope of `Dim wbfinal As Workbook` will make it being alive only until the respective Sub will end.  It does no exist for `Sub WorkWithFinalFile()`. It must be declared globally, on top of the module (in the declarations area. 2. Using exactly the existing code  it will always be the last one. You should globally declare two such variables: `Public initWb as Worbook, finalWb as workbook` and the picking code should be adapted:

Comment: `If initWb is nothing then Set initWb = Workbooks(FileNameFinal)` `Else` `Set  finalWb = Workbooks(FileNameFinal)`  `End If`. Then, use `initWb.Activate`...

Comment: @Notus_Panda thank you for your answer. I tried the following:
Sub WorkWithFinalFile(wbfinal As String)

Workbooks(wbfinal).Activate

End Sub but this will made pop up the maro selection menu, did I do it correctly? How would you modify the above code?

Comment: @FaneDuru thank you for your answer, I have 2 subs , I added the 2nd one also now

Comment: But it is (almost) the same `Sub`. If you like this way, it is enough to **delete the workbook variables from both Subs** and globally declare them **on top of the standard module**. `Public wbworking As Workbook, wbfinal As Workbook`. Now you changed the variables scop and you can use them in other Subs.  `wbworking.Activate` or `wbfinal.Activate`... If you ready my above comment you can use the same sub and use `If wbworking is nothing then` `Set wbworking = Workbooks(FileNameFinal)` `Else` `Set  wbfinal = Workbooks(FileNameFinal)` `End If`. **Workbooks globally declared**!

Comment: @FaneDuru, works , thank you :)

Comment: I was not doubts about working... But which version did you choose? The one using two picker subs? Or only one Sub easily adapted? You can even adapt the `.Title` in the same way...

Comment: @FaneDuru I used the 2 subs , 1 file one sub

Comment: It looks simpler, but maybe it's time to improve your skills... :)

Answer (score 0):

Turn your select file code into a function that only returns the path to the file as a string.  Then call the function twice - once for each file.
The file paths are returned to your main procedure and you can play with them there.

Also have a read of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) as selecting/activating a file *really* isn't needed.

```
Public Sub SelectFinalOptima()

    'Get file paths for the two files.
    Dim FileName1 As String
    FileName1 = GetFileName("Please select Optima Final from last month.")
    
    Dim FileName2 As String
    FileName2 = GetFileName("Please select other file.")
    
    'Only continue if two files have been selected.
    If FileName1 <> "" And FileName2 <> "" Then
    
        'Open the two files and assign to variables.
        Dim wbFinal As Workbook
        Set wbFinal = Workbooks.Open(FileName1)
        
        Dim wbOther As Workbook
        Set wbOther = Workbooks.Open(FileName2)
        
        'Copy value from A1 in wbFinal to A1 in wbOther.
        wbOther.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = wbFinal.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        
        'Copy range from wbFinal to wbOther.
        wbFinal.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B3").Copy Destination:=wbOther.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1")
    
    End If
    
End Sub

'This function will return the full path to the selected file.
Public Function GetFileName(Optional TitleText As String = "Open File") As String
    
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = TitleText
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Optima Final", "*.xlsx"
    
        If .Show = True Then
          GetFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: thank you for this one, it didn't work all the way , but I can use elements of this code :)